# Diferentes maneiras de transmitir um vídeo

Tags: streaming, vídeo

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde o administrador irá fazer upload de vídeos e então os alunos irão assistir. Um portal de cursos à distância.

Utilizo atualmente o serviço de hospedagem da LocaWeb, e estou pensando em subir os vídeos para esse servidor, e apontar o *player* da aplicação para lá para que os alunos possam assistir. Quais as desvantagens disso? Quando devo considerar usar um servidor de *streaming*? Nesse caso, quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar meu próprio servidor de streaming, em vez de um serviço já existente como YouTube ou Vimeo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de fatores como privacidade, custo da largura de banda (que se relaciona com a quantidade de visitantes) e formatação dos vídeos adequada para web.

Se é seu servidor, em teoria, os arquivos estão baixo sua custódia, mas isso vai implicar em custos com segurança, tráfego, codificação dos vídeos, instalação de um media player no site. E [como bem lembra o bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32418/diferentes-maneiras-de-transmitir-um-v%C3%ADdeo/32451?noredirect=1#comment61508_32451), "*Se você abrigar no seu servidor o browser faz um 'falso streaming'*"

Se vai usar um [serviço de hosting para os vídeos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_hosting_services) <sup>en</sup>, o tráfego e a codificação não são problema, e a questão da privacidade vai variar conforme o serviço. No YouTube e Dailymotion, os vídeos marcados como privados só podem ser acessados por outros usuários do serviço quando estão logados. O YT tem a opção de deixar o vídeo *unlisted* e só quem tem a URL consegue ver, mas basta um Twitter com o link e já era. O Vimeo Premium tem a opção de liberar a reprodução só pra determinados domínios e assim pode-se deixar o vídeo atrás de um CMS para usuários registrados.

O artigo acima da Wikipedia tem umas tabelas bem legais comparando os diversos serviços. Separei aqueles cujos players são multiplataforma (os links são pra outros artigos na Wiki, em inglês também): 
[blip.tv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blip.tv), [DaCast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DaCast), [Dailymotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dailymotion), [Flickr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flickr), [Internet Archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive), [MetaCDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaCDN), [Viddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viddler), [Vimeo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimeo), [vzaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vzaar), [Youku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youku), [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube).
<sup>{ o Youku é lá na China, fica como curiosidade antropológica :) }</sup>

Nunca usei, mas acho que vale a pena pesquisar sobre os [Hangouts no Google+](https://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/). E, finalmente, o artigo da Wiki.pt para [Streaming de mídia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming) também é interessante.

Comment: Ou seja, o ideal é eu estar contratando um serviço para estar disponibilizando isso para mim?

Comment: Como disse, depende. Você vai ter que avaliar seus recursos e estudar as opções de cada serviço para poder decidir o que é melhor.

Comment: @Felipe Se você abrigar no seu servidor o browser faz um "falso streaming". Se os vídeos forem longos e tiver muita gente assistindo ao mesmo tempo, pode não dar pra atender todo mundo direito. Se tiver como contratar um serviço pago pra cuidar de encoding e streaming/banda, fica mais parrudo.

Comment: Pode ser caso pra hospedar em alguma CDN. Os grandes hosts normalmente tem suporte à criação de CDNs.

Comment: A opção CDN é legal sim, mas envolve toda a questão de renderização e programação, um trabalho arretado. Eu usei o Vimeo $ num site de video aulas pela opção de deixar o video privado e limitar a um domínio.